# How can i delete default button widget in Thingworx?

Tags: thingworx

I want to delete default button widget and replace it with my own custom widget. I don't want to see default one. Even tough i deleted button widget from "Thingworx/Common/thingworx/widgets/button". It still active in ide.

Is there any way that i can completely remove default widget from system.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try restarting Tomcat after you deleted the folder? Not sure why you would want to delete the default button. If you want to replace it with a custom widget, you can have both and just not use the default.

Comment: yes, i tried to restart tomcat. I don't want other users to see default widget

Comment: You may remove it from Combined.XXX.js file ( from Thingworx/Composer/js and Thingworx/Runtime/js folders )

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it generates again even tough i deleted from combined.xxx.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace some kinf of widget with your custom you need to name it properly.

In your custom-button.js files find this lines:

```
/*global Encoder,TW */
TW.IDE.Widgets.custom-button= function () {
...
```

and replace it with standard button definition which is:

```
/*global Encoder,TW */
TW.IDE.Widgets.button= function () {
...
```

Standard button will be replaced with your custom one.